# Does the mitzvah of knowing Torah exist as separate from mitzvah of learning Torah?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, torah-study, mitzvah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

According to views of some authorities (Shulchan Aruch HaRav and others), learning without pronouncing words or listening to Torah recordings does not qualify as the mitzvah of Talmud Torah. Consequently, it seems that one is able to learn Torah quietly or via recordings without fulfilling the mitzvah of Talmud Torah.

According to these views, would such learning qualify as a mitzvah?
If not, is time spent learning quietly considered bittul Torah according to these views?

Comment: I'm not sure if those opinions agree there's such a concept of "yedias HaTorah"

Comment: See the Maharal on avot 2-30 about אם למדת תורה הרבה נותנים לך שכר הרבה that contradicts lichora gemara berachot אחד המרבה ואחד הממעיט ובלבד שיהא לבו לשמים, if I remember right he dvides the learning in two mitsvot, עמל וידיעה. Result a a great quantity of tora and action as a great effort for tora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R. Yisrael Salanter explains that there are two distinct aspects of studying Torah: “learning” Torah and “knowing” Torah. He explains that these two aspects are derived from different scriptural sources.

> הנה במצות תלמוד תורה יש בזה שני ענינים אחד למוד התורה  שני ידיעות  התורה מצות למוד התורה הוא מן הכתוב והגית בו יומם ולילה וכמו שכתב הרמב״ם והטור ושלחן ערוך בריש הלכות תלמוד תורה וזה לשונו כל אדם מישראל חיב בתלמוד תורה כו׳ שנאמר והגית בו יומם ולילה עין שם והנה למצוה זו של למוד התורה כל מהשלומד מקים המצות עשה והגית בו יומם ולילה הן מקרא או משנה גמרא הלכות ואגדות שכלן נתנו למשה מסיני וכמו שהאריך בזה בספר נפש החיים שער ד׳ פרק ו׳ עין שם ואף שלא יוכל לפסוק דין מתוך מקרא או משנה וכל שכן מן אגדה בכל זאת יוצא ידי מצות למוד התורה
>
> אולם הגדר השני במצות תלמוד תורה הוא ידיעות התורה והוא מה שאמרו חכמינו ז״ל בקדושין דף ל׳ ושננתם שיהו דברי תורה מחדדים בפיך שאם ישאל לך אדם דבר אל תגמגם ותאמר לו אלא אמר לו מיד שנאמר אמר לחכמה אחותי את ואומר קשרם על לוח לבך כו׳ ואומר חציך שנונים כו׳ ופרש רש״י יהו מחדדים בפיך חזר עליהם ובדק בעמקם שאם ישאלך אדם לא תצטרך לגמגם כו׳ אמר לחכמה אחותי את שתהא בקי בה כאחותך שאסורה לך עין שם

A few paragraphs later he explains that it is permissible to waste time from “learning” Torah in pursuit of “knowing” Torah:

> וכאשר נשכיל בינה נמצא כי יש דברים שהתר למלאות המטרה של מצות ידיעת התורה מה שלא היה ענין למצות למוד התורה וכמו בטול הזמן כי לשם ידיעות התורה שהוא יכולת הלמוד רשאי לבטל זמן לילך מעיר לעיר גם להרחיק נדוד לחפש אחר רב גדול לבקש תורה מפיו ולקבל ממנו דרכי הלמוד והעיון וכן לבלות זמן על עתות מנוחה ושנה מה שנחוץ לו לפי טבעו שיהיה אחר כך דעתו צלולה עליו ביותר להבין ולהשכיל בעמק העיון אשר כל זה לא היה ענין למצות למוד התורה בלבד כמובן

Comment: I will hopefully add a full translation later.

Answer (score 1):

See SA OC 47.4

> המהרהר בדברי תורה האינו צריך לברך. והוא הדין ודיכול זלפסוק דין בלא נתינת טעם לדבריו (ר"ן פרק קמא דשבת ופרק כל הצלמים כתב דהוי כהרהור): ‏

The SA says in name of the Ran in Masechet Shabbat that one who is thinking tora doesn't need to bless for this Tora activity. The Ran is based on the principle that thinking is not equivalent to speaking, e.g. for blessing.

But the Beur Halacha discusses this issue.

> עיין בביאור הגר"א שמקשה ע"ז דהלא הרהור בתורה הוא ג"כ מצוה כדכתיב והגית בו יומם ולילה ובנשמת אדם רוצה לדחות הקושיא ועיין בבנין עולם שמשיג על הנ"א ומסכים להגר"א. אמנם מה דמשמע שם מיניה דלהגר"א הרהור בתורה הוא כדבור ממש ומחמת זה כתב שם דמה שכתב הרמ"א בסימן ס"ח דמי שלומד ע"י הרהור וכו' לית ביה איסורא וכו' הוא אזיל לשיטתו בכאן דמסכים בהג"ה להמחבר דאפילו בתורה הרהור לאו כדיבור דמי משא"כ לשיטת הגר"א יהיה איסורא אפילו ע"י הרהור דחשיב הפסק בברכות ק"ש ולענ"ד לא כיון יפה דגם הגר"א מודה דאפילו בתורה הרהור לאו כדיבור אלא דס"ל דגם ההרהור הוא מצוה כדכתיב והגית בו יומם ולילה וכ"מ לשונו להמעיין בו היטב ועוד ראיה ברורה לדברי דאל"ה מאי מקשה הגמרא בשבת ק"נ ע"א מי אר"י הרהור לאו כדיבור דמי והא"ר יוחנן בכל מקום מותר להרהר בד"ת חוץ מבהמ"ר וכו' התם נמי כתיב ולא יראה בך ערות דבר וכו' הלא לענין ד"ת לכו"ע הרהור כדבור וא"כ אפילו אם ולא יראה קאי ע"ז ג"כ הרהור אסור אלא ודאי כמו שכתבנו ודוק:‏

The Beur Halacha says that the GRA objects that even Tora thinking is a Mitsva, on the basis of Gemara. The Gemara says that there is an allusion on the pasuk "you must think about it  on days and night. And the Beur Halacha adds a proof to the objection of the GRA, it is not permitted to think Tora words in bath house.

So, at first glance it is a machloket about thinking.

But listening seems to be more similary to speaking than thinking because of the principle שומע כעונה, that is hearing a speaker is like saying what he does.

this [link](http://halachayomit.co.il/he/QuestionDetails.aspx?ID=2957) is a Shiur of Rav Ovadia Yosef and explains on the basis of Tosfot Succa 52, that if you hear a recorded voice there is no din Shomea Keone, so it seems that listening a record of voice is no more than thinking. So, if thinking doesn't fulfill the mitsva criterion, since there is no shomea keone in recorded voice, to listen it doesn't fulfill the criterion of mitsva. From a svara point of view, listening record is as reading with eyes, without speaking.

See also [this post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73727/9215)

Comment: The question specifically limits the question to authorities who hold that thinking is not Limmud Torah, so not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: @Tesvov Right, that is what I wrote in name of Rav Ovadia Yosef and see also the link to an otther post. The Gemara Succa about the great Bet kneeset of Alexandria and the tosfot saying that there is no shomea keone